# R read.table csv where text field contains enters

Tags: r, csv, line-breaks, enter, read.table

I have an SQL query result exported to csv format with ";" as a separator. it should contain 5 columns:

```
order_id (str), 
user_rating (int), 
user_feedback (str), 
created_by (str), 
created_on (date)
```

Problem is that users can have comments spanning multiple lines in the user_feedback field. While in SQL it is coerced to a nice single line view. But for the exported csv the dataset would not read in properly.

`fread()` from data.table and `read.table()` both failed. I finally got it to read in as 1 column using:

```
data1 <- read.table('myFile.csv', stringsAsFactors = F, header = F, 
sep = "\t", allowEscapes = T, quote = "")
```

The problem now is as follows: the query result contains 50000 rows, but the csv is read in as 50267 rows. From checking the data, it seems it took `user_feedback` that contained 'enters' and read those in as separate rows.

How do I import this data properly, so with the `user_feedback` data for every row into a single string field?

Comment: If you have `;` as a separater, you should use `sep = ";"`. Did you try that? Furthermore: it is alsways good to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: I tried using the actual separator first, but that makes it break: `Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, : line 79 did not have 5 elements`
Since the problem is actually getting the dataset into R, I'm not quite sure how to create a reproducible example of the data.

Comment: What happens if you include the parameter `fill = TRUE`?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but yielded the same result unfortunately.

Comment: As I said in my first comment: if you don't include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610), that will make it a lot harder for people to help you.

Comment: I know, I'll see if I can create a sample and upload that to an S3 bucket.

Comment: Why not just include it in the question?

Comment: @DaReal can simply `dput(head(df))` and paste the sample here .

Comment: Also have a close look at line 79 of your csv file, since (as the error tells you) that's where `read.table` is getting tripped up.

Comment: Use `readLines`. The using `count.fields` determine line numbers where the number of fields is short. Append those to the preceding line without the "\n" and then read with `read.table`. Pretty sure there are worked examples in SO and Rhelp.